the expected value of the square of the distance of random two points on a circle.
Here is a problem from this year's MathCounts.

Two points are randomly and independently chosen on the circumference of a circle of radius 6. What is the expected value of the square of the distance between these two points?

The provided answer is 72.
I did it as following:
Let the circle be centered at the origin. Fix $A=(6,0)$ and let $B=(6\cos\theta,6\sin\theta)$. The square of the distance between $A$ and $B$  is
$$
d^2=\left(6\cos\theta-6\right)^2+(6\sin\theta)^2=72-72\cos\theta.
$$
Assume that the angle $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,2\pi]$. Then the expected value is calculated as
$$
E=\frac1{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}(72-72\cos\theta)d\theta=72.
$$
My question is that: is there any elementary solution for this problem? MathCounts competition is for 6,7,8 graders only. This computation is not proper. Thanks a lot.

Hint: Pythagorean theorem yields a one-line/idea solution. $ E = \frac{ 12^2}{2} = 72$.

Don't use images.

While the more precise calculus statement indeed seems out of scope, it can be presented rather intuitively using algebra alone. If $B=(x,y)$, then the quantity of interest is $$d^2=(6-x)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2-6x+36=72-6x.$$ But $x$ is just as likely to be positive as negative, therefore its expected value is zero and the expected value of $d^2$ is $36$. (One could even dispense with fixing $A$ and instead choose $A=(x_1,y_1), B=(x_2,y_2)$. Then the final observation is that the products $x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2$ should each average to zero.)

I am trying to understand Calvin Lin's hint:  For any $B_1\neq (-6,0)$, there is always a unique point $B_2$ on the circle so that $\angle B_1AB_2=90^\circ$ and $B_1B_2=12$ is the diameter. Then the average of $d^2(A,B_1)$ and $d^2(A,B_2)$ is $\frac12(d^2(A,B_1)+d^2(A,B_2))=\frac12d^2(B_1,B_2)=\frac{12^2}2=72$. Expected value is the average value if all points are uniformly distributed. Hence, it is 72.
